# Hiding projects classes

Tags: c++, .net

I am a little noob at managing different projects into a large one, but i have 3 projects which are libraries (yes they all do very different things). Those 3 libraries are used by another project and that project is used by the "user" project.

The problem is those three libraries needs to be visible to the fourth project but not the fifth project which is managed by the "user". How can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The .lib files contain sets of .obj files with the implementation of the libraries. You need to keep all symbols in the .lib files public so that the linker can resolve all inter-library dependencies.

When you want to define two sets of visibility of the library contents you should use two header files that publish the desired interface. For the "public" interface you will obviously less types and prototypes in the header file.